# Failing to open .txt file on C++ Windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, debugging, memory

I'm failing to open a `.txt` file using `std::ifstream file` and `file.open()`. I want to use an indirect PATH (starting in the folder the `.exe` file is in - `\program_folder`), but using a complete PATH (`C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop\C++\program_folder\inputs\test.txt`) also didn't work.

```
#include <iostram>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
   char c;
   std::vector<std::string> inputs;
   inputs.push_back("C:\\inputs\\test.txt");
   int a; int b;
   std::ifstream file;
   file.open(inputs[0]);
   if (file.is_open()){
      c = file.get();
      file.close();
   }
   else {std::cout << "\nfail to open file";}
}
```

As output, I'm getting the fail massage.

Comment: This means the file does not exist where you say it does or you don't have permission to read it. Perhaps you named the file incorrectly to test.txt.txt. Windows explorer hides extensions by default and this can lead to having double extensions on known files.

Comment: `arquivo.close();`??

Comment: arquivo is the portuguese name of file, I missed it when I transleted the code in arquivo.close()

Comment: There's no standard way in C++ to use a path relative to where the exe is. The current working directory is set by the platform, and although you can change it, there is no standard way to find out where the exe is.

Comment: Also `"C:\\inputs\\test.txt"` is not a relative path, that would be `"inputs\\test.txt"`.

Comment: If you are running this in the Visual Studio IDE, the default folder when executing from the IDE is the folder containing the project file defined in the debugging settings for your project as $(ProjectDir). Other IDEs may set the working directory to the location of the executable.

Comment: You can use the Win32 API `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` to get the full path to the `.exe` file, then manipulate it as needed. For instance, by assigning it to a C++17 `std::filesystem::path` and then calling its `replace_filename()` method with the desired relative path as input.  Or, using the Win32 API `PathRemoveFileSpec()` and `PathCombine()` (or newer equivalents).

Answer (score -1):

`"C::\\inputs\\test.txt"` was not a relative path i had to use `"inputs\\test.txt"`

thanks to john in the comments.

Comment: The initial working directory of a process is meant for resolving user-supplied filepaths on the command line and as the default location for output files. It is incorrect to rely on the initial working directory for private application resources, since it depends entirely on the parent process. Use a well-known location such as the application directory, which you can get as the dynamic variable "\_\_APPDIR\_\_" via `GetEnvironmentVariableW`, or dervied from the executable path from `GetModuleFileNameW` with `hModule` as `NULL`.